# Using MS Graph PowerShell SDK in Azure pipeline for granting access to Managed identity

Tags: azure-pipelines, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am deploying an Azure function that needs to access Microsoft Graph API (reading App registrations) using Managed Identity.  The function is deployed using Azure pipelines, this would mean that the pipeline need to provision the MI, with necessary permissions to read app registrations.  I have taken below approach to accomplish this, and facing permission issue while provisioning access,

- The Azure pipeline service connection has app-roles **Application.ReadWrite.All**, **ServicePrincipalEndpoint.ReadWrite.All**.
- App role assignment to MI is done using Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK (using Powershell pipeline task).  The relevant code is below

```
Install-Module Microsoft.Graph -Scope CurrentUser
    
$context = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext
$graphToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.microsoft.com").AccessToken
$aadToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.windows.net").AccessToken

Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $graphToken 
$AppPrincipal =  Get-MgServicePrincipal -Filter "Id eq '$AppPrincipalId'" 
Write-Host " $AppPrincipal " + $AppPrincipal
$GraphServicePrincipal = Get-MgServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'"

$PermissionName = "Application.Read.All"
$AppRole = $GraphServicePrincipal.AppRoles | Where-Object {$_.Value -eq $PermissionName -and $_.AllowedMemberTypes -contains "Application"}
$appRoleAssignment = @{
    "principalId" = $AppPrincipal.Id
    "resourceId"  = $GraphServicePrincipal.Id
    "appRoleId"   = $AppRole.Id
}
New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId $AppPrincipal.Id -BodyParameter $appRoleAssignment | Format-List
```

While executing `Get-MgServicePrincipal` statement the below error is thrown,

```
##[error]Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

I had similar code work with `Get-AzureADServicePrincipal`, but not able to figure out how to accomplish this with MG Powershell (the AzureAD will soon be deprecated).  What am i doing wrong in the implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the pipeline permission issue after providing **Directory.Read.All** (Required for `Get-MgServicePrincipal`), **AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All** (Required for `New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment`).  Below is the full list of permission required to accomplish the app role assignment from pipeline scoped to App registration and Service principal registration using Graph API,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to do this using the Graph API via the Azure CLI. The documentation for which is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)

As described in the documentation, the Graph API roles you'll need to assign to the Service Principal you are using as the Service Connection in your Dev Ops pipeline are:

`AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All` = 06b708a9-e830-4db3-a914-8e69da51d44f
and either
`Applicaton.Read.All` = 9a5d68dd-52b0-4cc2-bd40-abcf44ac3a30
or
`Directory.Read.All` = 7ab1d382-f21e-4acd-a863-ba3e13f7da61

What the documentation does not state though is that the Service Principal you are using to assign the role must also have the Azure AD role `Privileged Role Administrator` which you can set in the Azure Portal. As described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/manage-roles-portal)

With that in place your Service Principal can assign roles to other Service Principals in your DevOps pipeline like this

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'DevOpsRoleSettingServiceConnection'
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      $spId="f9eb88af-f0cf-490a-85f7-65b04d09cc18"
      $appReadAll="9a5d68dd-52b0-4cc2-bd40-abcf44ac3a30"
      az rest `
        --method post `
        --uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/$spId/appRoleAssignments `
        --body `
        ("{" +
            "'principalId':'$spId'," +
            "'resourceId':'7779fb29-7f94-4a6c-bc0e-b61d27fd9546'," +
            "'appRoleId':'$appReadAll'" +
        "}") --headers "Content-Type=application/json"
```

Note that the `$spId` here is the Object ID of the Service Principal, not the App ID.

I find this a bit simpler than using the PowerShell commands. You don't have to authenticate PowerShell or install any modules since everything you need is already present in the Azure CLI environment context.